# How to pass url dynamically to rest api?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to pass the get api urls for fetch the data from one application to another application. I have temporary solution as the url details in queryParams and use it in another application. Is there any professional way to implement for build url with dynamically?

In my first application i have build the url as below

```
async buildUrl(applicationId, getUrl) {
        let url = this.filterBaseurl + `datafilter/get-filter-utility?entityId=${applicationId}&connectorName=${this.connectorName}&entityName=${this.entityName}&getUrl=${getUrl}`
        return url
    }
```

example result of above function is

```
${baseUrl}/datafilter/get-filter-utility?entityId=12345678&connectorName=greenhouse&entityName=engagement-request&getUrl=jobs
```

in my another application i have calling the required api url

```
let queryparams = req.queryParams
let url = ${queryparams.getUrl}/{queryparams.entityId}
let response = await this.restProvider.get(url)
```

the way i have implement with queryParams is unprofessional, is there any better way to build the api url dynamically. one difficulty is i shouldn't call second application's api endpoint from first application.

Comment: I'm not sure what "unprofessional" means in this context. You do have a couple of issues: `buildUrl` doesn't need to be `async` and ``let url = ${queryparams.getUrl}/{queryparams.entityId}`` should probably be ``let url = `${queryparams.getUrl}/${queryparams.entityId}``, and I think the syntax is `req.params`,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var x1 = new URL("https://example.org")
x1.searchParams.append("x", "y")
```